# Can I automatically get user token?

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, restfb

I want to make a simple app, that logins to my page when launched and makes a post. But now I have to paste my token manually into code.

```
        String token = "MY_COOL_TOKEN";    
        FacebookClient client = new DefaultFacebookClient(token);    
        User user = client.fetchObject("me", User.class);    
        client.publish(
            "me/feed", 
            FacebookType.class, 
            Parameter.with("message", "Amazing hackerman Hello World message")
    );
```

I wonder, can I somehow give this app my login/passwords and then obtain a token from code?

Comment: Pass via `main(String[] args)`, or read from a file, or have a simple swing/FX interface...

Comment: not possible. just use an extended page token.